# set_interaction example with custom vector not working

Tags: c++, vector, set-intersection

I'm looking to get intersection of two custom vectors `- v and w -` and then deleting common elements from original vector `- v`. But somehow size of `y` in my case is `0` always

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    int x;
    A(int i) { x = i; } 
    ~A() {}
    void getx() { cout << x << " "; } 
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const A&a) {
        cout << a.x;
        return o;
    }
};

struct mycomparer {
    bool operator()(const A* a, const A* b) {
        return a->x < b->x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<A*> v;
    v.push_back(new A(1));
    v.push_back(new A(2));
    v.push_back(new A(4));
    v.push_back(new A(3));
    v.push_back(new A(5));

    vector<A*> w;
    w.push_back(new A(3));
    w.push_back(new A(2));

    vector<A*> y;
    vector<A*>::iterator it, st;
    it = set_intersection(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin(), w.end(), y.begin(), mycomparer());

    cout << " y size "  << y.size() << endl;

    if (y.size()) {
        for (st = y.begin(); st != y.end(); st++)
            v.erase(st);
    }

    for (st = v.begin(); st != v.end(); st++) {
        printf("%d ", (*st)->x);
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is just a sample which I wrote and my intend is not to check for any other C++ rules.

Comment: From the spec: "Elements are compared using the given binary comparison function comp and the __ranges must be sorted__ with respect to the same."

Comment: Aside: You don't need `new` to create objects. `vector<A> v; v.push_back(A(1));` etc.

Comment: Recommended read: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721); [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500313); [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907)

Comment: std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), mycomparer());

    std::sort(w.begin(), w.end(), mycomparer());

    it = set_intersection(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin(), w.end(), y.begin(), mycomparer());
This gives segfault in set_intersection @Albjenow

Comment: @Caleth OK then ... at least it's half-minimal code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't obeyed the requirements of [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

> Constructs a sorted range beginning at `d_first` consisting of elements that are found in both **sorted** ranges `[first1, last1)` and `[first2, last2)`. If some element is found m times in `[first1, last1)` and n times in `[first2, last2)`, the first `std::min(m, n)` elements will be copied from the first range to the destination range. The order of equivalent elements is preserved. The resulting range cannot overlap with either of the input ranges.

Neither `v` nor `w` are sorted w.r.t `mycomparer`. That's the first undefined behaviour.

Just passing `y.begin()` does not mean elements are added to `y`, for that you need `std::back_inserter(y)`. That's the second undefined behaviour.

You haven't obeyed the requirements of `std::vector::erase`. It's argument is an iterator into *that* `vector`. You are using an iterator from `y`, not `v`. That's the third undefined behaviour.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class A{
    public:
    int x;
    A(int i) { x = i; } 
    ~A() {}
    void getx() { cout << x << " "; } 
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, const A&a) {
        cout << a.x;
        return o;
    }
};

struct mycomparer {
    bool operator()(const A* a, const A* b) {
        return a->x < b->x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> v;
    v.push_back(new A(1));
    v.push_back(new A(2));
    v.push_back(new A(4));
    v.push_back(new A(3));
    v.push_back(new A(5));

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), mycomparer());

    std::vector<A*> w;
    w.push_back(new A(3));
    w.push_back(new A(2));

    std::sort(w.begin(), w.end(), mycomparer());

    std::vector<A*> y;
    set_intersection(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin(), w.end(), std::back_inserter(y), mycomparer());

    std::cout << " y size "  << y.size() << std::endl;

    for (st = y.begin(); st != y.end(); st++)
        v.erase(std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), *st));

    for (st = v.begin(); st != v.end(); st++) {
        std::cout << (*st)->x) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As an aside, you could instead use [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) to find the elements in `v` not in `w` directly.

Comment: So I was missing sorting of my original vectors and use of back_inserter. Thanks.

Comment: Seems I was too late... well, you get that when trying to point out all the issues with the code, like the big memory leak and coding style issues. I have to do more quick fixes to get to 23.2k points

Comment: @AshishMalhotra And using a interator from `v` to pass to `v.erase`

Comment: @JHBonarius yes, I just went for the UB

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your code... I just put them in modified code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// don't using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    int x; // don't expose internals
public:
    constexpr A(int i) noexcept : x(i) {}

    constexpr int GetX() const noexcept { return x; } // don't make a getter to print

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const A& a) {
        o << a.x; // don't push to cout in an ostream operator <<
        return o;
    }
};

// use lambda instead of functors
static constexpr auto mycomparer =
[](std::shared_ptr<A> const& a, std::shared_ptr<A> const& b) noexcept {
        return a->GetX() < b->GetX();
};

int main()
{
    // you were not deleting the new elements: memory leak
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> v; // e.g. use smart pointers
    v.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(1));
    v.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(2));
    v.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(4));
    v.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(3));
    v.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(5));

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> w;
    w.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(3));
    w.push_back(std::make_shared<A>(2));

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> y;

    //you have to sort before calling set_intersection
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), mycomparer);
    std::sort(std::begin(w), std::end(w), mycomparer);

    std::set_intersection(
        std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), // use const iterators
        std::cbegin(w), std::cend(w),
        std::back_inserter(y), mycomparer); // you cannot iterate over an empty array. Use the backinserter

    std::cout << " y size " << y.size() << '\n';

    // you cannot use an iterator to a vector y to delete from vector v!
    //if (y.size() > 0) { // not required
        for (auto const& el : y)
            v.erase(std::find(std::cbegin(v), std::cend(v), el)); 
    //}

    for (auto const& el : v) {
        std::cout << el->GetX() << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n'; // prefer \n over endl for speed

    //return 0; // not required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) In vector `w` you should push `new A(2)` first, then `new A(3)`. For your actual code, your vectors must be sorted according to the comparator beforehand, as previously mentioned in commentaries, or you absolutely cannot use set_intersection.

2) vector `y` has size 0, because `set_intersection` does not *insert* new elements at iterator, but instead *assigns* with operator `=`. Instead of `y.begin()` you should use `std::back_inserter(y)`, which would actually insert elements on assignment.

Comment: 3) OP tries to use an iterator from `y` to `erase` an element from `v`.